# Obtener MAC de dispositivo mediante Apache Cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

Estoy desarrollando una Aplicación Móvil con Apache Córdova y necesito obtener la MAC del dispositivo ¿Es esto posible?  Si es así ¿Cómo la obtengo?.

Comment: has probado esto? https://github.com/mohamed-salah/MacAddress

Comment: Habia encontrado un plugin que obtiene la uuid y el numero de serie, pero ese no, gracias te cuento como me fue.

Comment: La mac como tal no creo, pero si el uuid, que es algo muy similar, eso lo puedes obtener con el plugin device: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/reference/cordova-plugin-device/index.html

Comment: @JorgeMejia Estuve buscando información de la uuid y vi que es posible cambiarla, no siempre es la misma para el celular.